# Fixed background scale transformation without affecting text within div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue involving `transform: scale`. I'd like to slowly have my background zoom up upon hover, but I don't want it to affect my text. (I've left out browser prefixes to shorten the length of the post.)

Here is my CSS:

```
#cont-nl {
    background: url('../img/nl.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 60vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}


#cont-nl:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="row" id="cont-nl">
        <div class="container t-blk-center">
            <div class="">
                <h1 class="align-left">Next Level Youth Ministry</h1>
                <div class="tab-brk"></div>
                <h3 class="align-left">For students 6th-12th grade.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The ideal solution

Use a percentage or pixel unit size for `background-size` and transition on hover to a larger `background-size` in order to zoom in.

#### Example

```css
#cont-nl {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAEjm.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 150%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-position: center;
  transition: background-size 6s;
}
#cont-nl:hover {
  background-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="cont-nl">
  <div class="container t-blk-center">
    <div class="">
      <h1 class="align-left">Next Level Youth Ministry</h1>
      <div class="tab-brk"></div>
      <h3 class="align-left">For students 6th-12th grade.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Limitation

As of April 2016, this is not ideal for use with centered background images. These cause a buggy, jumpy transition in all browsers.

---

### The alternative solution

#### Example 1

If there is no width and height for the element to inherit from its parent

Place the background image on a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before), which is then:

- positioned with `position: absolute` and `left: 0` / `top: 0`
- given `z-index: -1` to ensure that it will be layered underneath text
- set `height: 60vh` and `width: 100vw` with the values matching the parent.

The parent of the pseudo-element is given `position: relative`.

```css
#cont-nl {
    height: 60vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cont-nl:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAEjm.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cont-nl:hover:before {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="cont-nl"> 
        <div class="container t-blk-center">
            <div class="">
                <h1 class="align-left">Next Level Youth Ministry</h1>
                <div class="tab-brk"></div>
                <h3 class="align-left">For students 6th-12th grade.</h3>
            </div>
        </div> 
 </div>
```

---

#### Example 2

If the height and width can be inherited from the parent

Place the background image on a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before), which is then:

- positioned with `position: absolute` and stretched with `left / right / bottom / left` set to 0
- given `z-index: -1` to ensure that it will be layered underneath text

The parent of the pseudo-element is given `position: relative`.

```css
#cont-nl {
    height: 60vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cont-nl:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAEjm.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cont-nl:hover:before {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="cont-nl"> 
        <div class="container t-blk-center">
            <div class="">
                <h1 class="align-left">Next Level Youth Ministry</h1>
                <div class="tab-brk"></div>
                <h3 class="align-left">For students 6th-12th grade.</h3>
            </div>
        </div> 
 </div>
```

#### A note on browser prefixes

Head on over to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) to check native support for CSS properties. Properties such as `transform` and `transition` have fantastic browser support and prefixes are often unnecessary.

Comment: Here is a live link to the page that I'm building: http://newlife.greyzweb.com/pages/ministries/index.html

Comment: Yeah, there is no width or height for it to inherit. Easiest thing to do is place a height and width with `vw` and `vh` that matches its parent. In this case:  `#cont-nl:before { width: 100vw; height: 60vh; }` **Remove** the `right` and `bottom` property as well, leaving just `left: 0` and `top: 0`

Comment: No worries :) [bear in mind that the `vh` and `vm` units don't work with IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), so in IE land it will only support IE 9+