# Transition on a container with a background-image make text flickering

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a bug that make flickering the text elements inside a container who has a background-image when a transition on the container occur.

I have the issue in Chrome and Microsoft Edge.
Firefox doesn't seem to have an issue about that.

I include a code pen link with an example of the bug.
https://codepen.io/xGeekoo/pen/yLRzJrB

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/582/582200.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container:hover .bg-img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.heading-secondary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-img"></div>
  <h2 class="heading-secondary">This is a test</h2>
  <p class="paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, enim.
  </p>
</div>
```

Does it exist any trick to fix the issue ?

Comment: Cannot confirm with Chrome 108.0.5359.94 (Linux).

Comment: Are you talking about how the red gets darker when you mouse over? or at least the font changes some how on mouse over?

Comment: Yes, that impact the color and font-size/font-weight of text element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed background scale transformation without affecting text within div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466243/fixed-background-scale-transformation-without-affecting-text-within-div)

Comment: Not exactly, but changing background-size it's actually another way that doesn't impact the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying [`will-change: transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), to give a hint to the browser that the element may be transitioned at some point. This allows the browser to set up some things differently for rendering the elements, and may help the text appearance changing:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("https://images2.alphacoders.com/582/582200.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: -1;
  will-change: transform;
}

.container:hover .bg-img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.heading-secondary {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-img"></div>
  <h2 class="heading-secondary">This is a test</h2>
  <p class="paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, enim.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work. I all wonder if another way would be more appropriate in my context without impacting performance.